# My html code is not displaying on my website, what could be the issue?

Tags: html, css

I am expecting my modal to be displayed when I run the html file on any browser.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a CSS code also

Comment: do you use bootstrap? Have you add the relative js file?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `CSS (bootstrap)` code to the `HTML` file.

Use the code below in your file and try again!
Maybe that's what you are missing.

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

With the tags though!